# Using netbeans IDE for debugging PHP application

Tags: php, netbeans

We are using xampp with PHP in our local machine. We would like to use the netbeans IDE for debugging our application. We followed the steps as referred in https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/debugging.html#debuggingSession. We installed netbeans version 8.2

Currently we are able to configure the project and are able to set the break points.

But while executing, the application is not getting stopped at the break points

We also tried the setting ‘xdebug.extended_info = 1’ as referred in [Netbeans 8.0.2 Debugger Breakpoints Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31778824/netbeans-8-0-2-debugger-breakpoints-not-working). But still this is not working

Could you please suggest what we missed.

Thanks

Comment: Not really on-topic, but: PHP 5.5 has been EOL for a very long time. Please update as soon as possible to at least PHP 7 to ensure the security of your application.

Comment: We checked this with PHP 7 also